# DB2 for z/os V11 - how to get application id?

Tags: db2, zos

Can anybode give me a hint on how to extract the application id of my DB2 subsystem in z/os?

I tried the "V8 approach" from here: [Application ID from db2 8.1.5 on Z/OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714023/application-id-from-db2-8-1-5-on-z-os)
but my shop has not installed the jars for the import *com.ibm.db2.app.*;* so I can't go this way...

Is there another way to extract the application id?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The import file should have been installed as part of DB2 installation. Check with your DBA and/or sysprog.

Answer (score 1):

just found [this](https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20Chorus%2003%200%2000-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/Security%20Administration%20Site%20Preparation%20Guide/index.htm?toc.htm?2123940.html) on a CA-site, perhaps it helps:

> For DB2, use the DB2 command -DISPLAY DDF to determine the appropriate
>   value to use for the PassTicket application name.
>   If GENERICLU is not
>   defined, replace applid with the second part of the LUNAME.
>
> If GENERICLU is defined, use the second part of GENERICLU.
>
> If neither LUNAME or GENERICLU are defined, use the value of the
>   IPNAME.
>
> Sample output from the -DISPLAY DDF command follows:
>
> LOCATION LUNAME GENERICLU
>
> DA0GPTIB example.text1 example.text2
>
> TCPPORT=5122 SECPORT=5193 RESPORT=5124 IPNAME=-NONE
>
> In the sample
>   output, text1 and text2 represent the LUNAME and GENERICLU name,
>   respectively.   Note: When issuing a DB2 command from the z/OS
>   console, replace the hyphen (-) with the specific command prefix for
>   the DB2 region.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. My user-id seems to have no authority to submit DISPLAY commands... "DSN9016I  -RDFA '-DISPLAY DDF' COMMAND REJECTED, UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST"...

Comment: Well, why not ask your DBA what the id is - they should at least be able to do the `DISPLAY`.

Comment: Asking the DBA feels like cheating. ;-) But if that is the only way to find out the id, I will ask them.

Comment: The import file should have been installed as part of DB2 installation. Check with your DBA and/or sysprog.

Answer (score 0):

Technicaly the -DISPLAY GROUP command should give you a better chance but since you can't issue DB2 commands that doesn't help much.
You could "cheat" by issuing this select statment that will tell you the LOCATION of the DB2, it's usually the same as the Application ID:
Select current server from sysibm.sysdumy1;